# How to Unit test Web API calling Method

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling a Web Api method inside my Repository layer. Can anyone suggest how to test it using Mocking

Comment: a web api method (in fact, anything from a layer higher than the Repository) shouldn't be called from repository. It should be the other way around

Comment: Even if i call that from Service layer, i still need to know how to write a unit test for the method that calls it

Comment: How do you call the web api?

Comment: <code>this.httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("{SomeAddress}")); 
HttpResponseMessage response = this.httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;
var ApiResultObject = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<myObject>().Result;</code>

Answer (score 9):

If you want to mock the call to a Web API method you will have to abstract the code that is calling it.

So abstract it:

```
public interface IMyApi
{
    MyObject Get();
}
```

and then you could have a specific implementation of this interface that is using an HttpClient to call the actual API:

```
public class MyApiHttp: IMyApi
{
    private readonly string baseApiUrl;
    public MyApiHttp(string baseApiUrl)
    {
        this.baseApiUrl = baseApiUrl;
    }

    public MyObject Get()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = this.baseAddress;
            var response = client.GetAsync('/api/myobjects').Result; 
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your repository layer will simply take this abstraction as constructor argument:

```
public class Repository: IRepository
{
    private readonly IMyApi myApi;
    public Repository(IMyApi myApi)
    {
        this.myApi = myApi;
    }

    public void SomeMethodThatYouWantToTest()
    {
        var result = this.myApi.Get();
        ...
    }
}
```

Next in your unit test it's trivial to mock the access to the API using your favorite mocking framework. For example your the unit test with NSubstitute might look like this:

```
// arrange
var myApiMock = Substitute.For<IMyApi>();
var sut = new Repository(myApiMock);
var myObject = new MyObject { Foo = "bar", Bar = "baz" };
myApiMock.Get().Returns(myObject);

// act
sut.SomeMethodThatYouWantToTest();

// assert
...
```